# Is it possible in .Net to catch all unhandled exceptions from any method in a class before its passed up the call stack?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, .net-4.0, error-handling

**Problem:**

I would like to catch any exceptions from any method in a class so that I may record class specific data to the exception for logging before it is passed up the stack. I know that I can put a try-catch in every method of the class, but there are many methods and It seems there should be a more efficient way.

**Example of what I am currently doing:**

```
public class ClassA
{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public void Method1()
    {
        try
        {
           //Some code
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.Data.Add("x", x);
            ex.Data.Add("y", y);
            throw;
        }
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        try
        {
            //Some code
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.Data.Add("x", x);
            ex.Data.Add("y", y);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

**Example of what I would like to do:**

```
public class ClassB : IUnhandledErrorHandler
{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public void Method1()
    {
        //Some code
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        //Some code
    }

    void IUnhandledErrorHandler.OnError(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.Data.Add("x", x);
        ex.Data.Add("y", y);
        throw;
    }
}

public interface IUnhandledErrorHandler
{
    void OnError(Exception ex);
}
```

**Note:**
This class is a service in a WCF project and implements a ServiceContract. I have tried adding an ErrorHandler to the service's ChannelDispatcher. However, when the error reaches the ErrorHandler it is already beyond the scope of the class where the error occurred, so I cannot access the class details.

**Solution:**

```
public class ClassC
{
    public ClassC()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += OnError;
    }

    private int x;
    private int y;

    public void Method1()
    {
        //Some code
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        //Some code
    }

    private void OnError(object sender, System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Exception.Data["x"] = x;
        e.Exception.Data["y"] = y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this only for debugging? Are you wanting to send the exceptions to the client, or just keep them serverside?

Comment: Its for debugging/logging on the server side.

Comment: You should never use "throw ex;". That makes it look like the exception originally came from the location of the "throw ex;".

Comment: Thank you for catching that. I use just "throw" in my code, not sure why I had "throw ex" in my example.

Comment: The answer can be found [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129915/asp-net-exception-handling-logging

Comment: The answer can be found [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129915/asp-net-exception-handling-logging

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer will not work for my problem, as I would like to handle all exceptions not just user-defined exceptions. Also, I would not want my user-defined exceptions to be dependent on a specific logging implementation.

Comment: Instead of adding class-specific data, how about adding the class instance itself, and either serializing it to the Data dictionary, or using .ToString(). This would allow you generic handling, perhaps even using FirstChanceException.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you run on .NET 4, you might use the [FirstChanceException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception.aspx) event from the AppDomain.

Comment: This looks promising. I will attempt to implement it to see if it is a viable solution.

Comment: Good :-) Glad to know you achieved it :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by inheriting from System.ContextBoundObject.  It's not as pretty as you would hope, and I believe there probably is some significant overhead associated with it, but as far as I know it's the only way to do what you describe.

As requested here is further elaboration...as mentioned it ain't pretty, but here is a minimal implementation needed to make this work.  The main method of interest is the AOPSink.SyncProcessMessage method.  It is called prior to any method on a 'Test' object, and the call to NextSink.SyncProcessMessage(msg) is what actually invokes the originally called method.  You can inspect (and modify) which method was called and the parameters passed by playing with the IMessage parameter passed to SyncProcessMessage, and you can inspect/modify the return value (or thrown Exception) by playing with the IMessage returned from NextSink.SyncProcessMessage.  There is significant performance overhead for this functionality, so I wouldn't recommend it for high traffic objects outside of debugging purposes.

```
[AOP]
class Test : ContextBoundObject
{     
    public void TestMethod()     
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }      
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class AOPAttribute : ContextAttribute
{
    public AOPAttribute() : base("AOPAttribute") { }
    public override void GetPropertiesForNewContext(IConstructionCallMessage ctor)
    {
        ctor.ContextProperties.Add(new AOPProperty());
    }
    public override bool IsContextOK(Context ctx, IConstructionCallMessage ctorMsg)
    { 
        return false; 
    }
}

public class AOPProperty : IContextProperty, IContributeServerContextSink
{
    public IMessageSink GetServerContextSink(IMessageSink nextSink)
    {
        return new AOPSink(nextSink);
    }
    public string Name { get { return "AOP"; } }
    public bool IsNewContextOK(Context ctx) { return true; }
    public void Freeze(Context ctx) { }
}

public class AOPSink : IMessageSink
{
    public AOPSink(IMessageSink nextSink) { this.NextSink = nextSink; }
    public IMessageSink NextSink { get; private set; }
    public IMessage SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)
    {
        // inspect method+params by playing with 'msg' here
        IMessage m = NextSink.SyncProcessMessage(msg);
        // inspect returnval/exception by playing with 'm' here
        return m;
    }
    public IMessageCtrl AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I don't believe that object has any means of addressing the OP's question.

Comment: This may be too much overhead, since it will be used in production for logging. Also, is it possible to access the fields of the class from where the error was thrown?

Comment: Sure, you could encapsulate all the Context+Sink stuff in a base class with an abstract 'OnError' method which would be called from SyncProcessMessage....so you could then handle the exception right in the class that threw it (just like your 'what I would like to do' example)